# 'Required' Attribute in HTML is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

'required' attribute isn't working while submitting the form. I looked online for fix, but none of them solved my issues. Please look at the below code, I used required attribute in the first field, but when i click on submit, it's not showing any error.

Also, data-match="#email" doesn't seem to work to check to see if the email matches with confirm email.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Stripe Payment Demo</title>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/4.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 800px;
        }

        form {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="payment" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="uname">Full Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control" name="uname" maxlength="50" value="John" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="file">Select your picture :</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" id="myfile" name="file">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tag1">Search Keyword 1:</label>
                <input required type="text" class="form-control" id="tag1" name="tag1" maxlength="50" value="Enter keyword 1">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tag2">Search Keyword 2:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tag2" name="tag2" maxlength="50" value="Enter keyword 2">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="website">Website:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="website" name="website" maxlength="70"
                    value="Enter the website">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" maxlength="100"
                    pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" value="Enter your email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="confirmemail">Confirm Email:</label>
                <input type="confirmemail" class="form-control" id="confirmemail" name="email" maxlength="100"
                    data-match="#email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" value="Re-enter your email">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description">About you:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="description" maxlength="160" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>


        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] - your issue only needs 1 line of code, maybe with the `<form>` and `<button type=submit>` for completeness - the rest makes it confusing and makes people less likely to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You have pre-defined values in `value` attribute. Replace it with `placeholder`

```
<input required type="text" class="form-control" id="tag1" name="tag1" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter keyword 1">
```

Comment: Wondering how changing from 'Value' to 'Placeholder' would impact it. But, it worked! I could have never guessed it! 

You seem to have missed my another question. "data-match="#email" isn't working. I want to validate if both the emails match.

Comment: `data-match` was in bootstrap3, but not in 4 version. check it manually with JS @rakeshmehra

Answer (score 0):

**You need to Use Placeholder instead of Value in Input Tag:**

Your Code: `<input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control" name="uname" maxlength="50" value="John" required>`

Use following code: `<input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control" name="uname" maxlength="50" placeholder="John" required>`

Comment: There's no point reposting his entire code, it's often better to just point out the one place they're wrong, so that the solutions are more general.